# How can I have a div appear option class is selected within <select>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I want to show a `div` only if one of the option classes with the class `warning` is selected. I'm trying to do it with something like the following:

HTML:

```
<select id="country">
    <option class="warning" value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option class="warning" value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option class="noWarning" value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option class="warning" value="4">Option 4</option>
    <option class="noWarning" value="5">Option 5</option>
    <option class="warning" value="6">Option 6</option>    
</select>

<div id="hiddendiv" style="display:none">
    Test
</div>
```

Script:

```
$('#country').change(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('class') == 'warning'){
        $('#hiddendiv').show();
    }else if ($(this).attr('class') == 'nowarning'){
        $('#hiddendiv').hide();
    }
});
```

I know I need to somehow call the option class instead as it's just finding the class of the select box at the moment, I think.

Comment: Check your capitalization on `noWarning` inside the `else if`

Comment: Also, you probably want to use `hasClass()` instead of `attr('class')`.

Answer (score 1):

You should look up for the `option:selected` inside your `change` event handler, not `select` as it has no class itself, then use [`.hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) method

```
$('#country').change(function () {
  var selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
  $('#hiddendiv').toggle(selected.hasClass('warning'));
});
```

I have used [`.toggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method instead of `.show()` / `hide()` in the example above, as you don't need for `if` statement if you want the `div` to be shown only when the selected `option` has class `warning`.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kvddhw16/)

Answer (score 0):

I made some edits to your script and it work fine now:

```
$('#country').change(function () {
    var className = $(this).find('option:selected').attr("class");
  if (className == 'warning')
  {
    $('#hiddendiv').show();
  }
  else if (className == 'noWarning'){
    $('#hiddendiv').hide();
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/2bn8nLav/

Answer (score 0):

Use `option:selected` to get the option that is selected and then check the existence of the class..

`$('#country').change(function () {
 $('#hiddendiv').toggle($(this).find('option:selected').hasClass('warning'));
});`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking and equating class attribute value, use jQuery `hasClass` method, this gives the ability to add more classes to `option` in future, if need be.

```
$('#country').change(function() {
    var $selectedOption = $(this).find('option:selected'),
        $hiddenDiv = $('#hiddendiv');

    $selectedOption.hasClass('warning') ? $hiddenDiv.show() : $hiddenDiv.hide();
});
```

Demo : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ashwinaggarwal/5y9g2z1z/1/)